# Migrating from SSD to NVME using dd

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, migration

I have a 500GB SSD:

```
/dev/sdc2        457G  201G  234G  47% /
```

and a 1TB nvme:
`/dev/nvme0n1`

So I have ran the command to migrate:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/nvme0n1 bs=4M status=progress conv=sync,noerror
```

Afterwords when running `fdisk -l` I get the error:

```
GPT PMBR size mismatch (976773167 != 1953525167) will be corrected by write.
The backup GPT table is not on the end of the device. This problem will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Sabrent Rocket Q                        
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BEE8FD2F-22E4-4D07-A959-618E4EA7BE8B
```

Also when I try resize:

```
resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

What am I doing wrong? And also what should I do after the resize as both `/dev/sdc2` and `/dev/nvme0n1` have the same UUID and running `mount -a` won't know which to pick?

Comment: as ppl mentioning on the forums, you should copy partitions instead of the whole drive.  So what you need to do, create same size partition on nvme, copy then original partition to nvme, reinstall boot sector and grub menu on nvme and then you could resize the partition on nvme

Comment: Your if=/dev/sdc is the whole drive instead of a partition (sdc1). That was your mistake. dd is unforgiving of mistakes - it does *exactly* what you tell it to do, no matter how unwise.

Comment: What do I then do about `/boot/efi`?